# iOS 8 displays table view cell contents at incorrect height

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

My app displays correctly (as I've designed in IB and programmed in the code) in iOS 7:

[image]

On iOS 8, the exact same code at the same screen size displays this:

[image]

The height of the cell contents is different. Auto layout is on and the cell contents are completely tied to the bounds of the cell via leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints. I've heard about the new auto-size in iOS 8, but in my nib, the cell is *not* set to auto height, it has an explicit height defined. Why could this happen?

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't find any solutions until now

Comment: @wod my bad, found the answer but forgot to post it as an answer. I've posted it below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution. Xcode 6 automatically adds spacing constraints to margins, instead of superview. I haven't figured out what they mean by margins, but if you hold <kbd>option</kbd> key when adding constraints, those margins change back to superviews, allowing you to add regular constraints to superview.

Comment: I have added manual constraints programmatically not from Storyboard , always i have passing nil for options value.Do you have a good example in Auto-layout uitableview for iOS 8 in objective c or tutorial for Auto-layout in iOS 8

Comment: @wod I haven't actually looked for that yet. I try to use Storyboards as much as possible.